# Caching in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Where I work we have been caching pages using Zend Framework vs 1 for quite some time.  We are trying to update to Zend Framework 2 and I'm not sure how to cache our pages with a ttl.

```
use Zend\Cache\PatternFactory;

$cache = Zend\Cache\PatternFactory::factory('capture', array(
  'public_dir' => '/Users/mmaruri/Sites/Test/newsfeed',
  'index_filename' => 'index.php'
));

$requesturl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

//$cache->setOptions(new Zend\Cache\Pattern\PatternOptions(['storage' => 'filesystem', 'ttl' => 3600]));

//create an id based on the uri
$cache_identifier = md5($requesturl);

$isCached = $cache->has($cache_identifier);
$test = $cache->getOptions($cache_identifier);

if($isCached)
{
  $t = $cache->get($cache_identifier);
  header('Status: 200', true, 200);
  echo $t;
  return;
}
else
{
  $cache->start($cache_identifier);
}
```

I'm not sure what the difference is between the Storage Adapters and the Capture Cache pattern.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation:

> The CaptureCache pattern is useful for generating static resources to return via HTTP request.
>   on https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-cache/pattern/capture-cache/

And

> Storage adapters are wrappers for real storage resources such as memory or the filesystem, using the well known adapter pattern.
>   https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-cache/storage/adapter/

So you would use the CaptureCache for static resources such as images and you would use the Storage adapters for data that you want to cache for a given time (Time To Live) such as a list of rows from your database.

Comment: I just want to cache the whole page.  The capture-cache pattern allows me to do that through the start method.  I can't find a similar method in any of the storage adapters.

Comment: the storage adapter isn't meant for storing a whole page, it's meant to store objects. So if you want to use Capture-cache, you have two options:

1. write your own TTL implementation using the pattern.

2. use https://github.com/bramstroker/zf2-fullpage-cache as an alternative, it's more complicated that your current capture-cache solution, but it allows for a more versatile caching.